# How to force iTunes to use an external hard drive for storage?

Tags: itunes, external-hard-drive, download, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to redirect itunes to external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/30630/how-to-redirect-itunes-to-external-hard-drive)

I want iTunes to store all downloaded files on an external hard drive. Is that possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> iTunes Media Folder Location